# SHOW PROCESSLIST shows only 20 connections, while server sais "has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections"

Tags: mysql, connection, processlist

I am not what's the problem and how to look at it:

SHOW PROCESSLIST shows only 20 connections, while server sais "has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections", which is 400.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the error mentions `max_user_connections`? This is limit per individual MySQL user, not for the entire server and by default is 0, which means that every user can use all available connections. `max_connections` specifies the absolute number of connections MySQL can accept at one time and this is probably set to 400 on your server.

`SHOW PROCESSLIST` will always show you all active connections. However maybe your client limits its output.

You can check the server variables via SQL command `show variables like 'max%connections';` which will output both settings:

```
mysql> show variables like 'max%connections';
+----------------------+-------+
| Variable_name        | Value |
+----------------------+-------+
| max_connections      | 300   |
| max_user_connections | 0     |
+----------------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: If those are short-lived connections (for example PHP connects, sends few query and then disconnects under 1s), then it is possible that at some time all 30 were used, but few seconds after that only 20 were used... So you need to increase the limit for your user.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure, you have proper [process permission](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_process) . If you dont have right to view other users' process, show process list wont show them